# Why I'm not able to see the logs of python task on UI in airflow if I'm using a user other than root

Tags: python, logging, airflow

I have installed airflow on two machines. On one machine I'm able to see the airflow logs of python task on UI and in another machine I'm not able to see the logs on UI if I'm running the DAG with a user other than root. If I use root I'm able to see the logs. I have checked the airflow.cfg everything looks same in both machines. I'm not able to figure out how to fix this issue.

I tried changing the permissions of all the files under airflow home directory. but no luck.

Comment: have you set the airflow user , see https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/howto/docker-compose/index.html#setting-the-right-airflow-user

Comment: I'm using Local executor and I have not installed it using docker. I followed the airflow documentation.

Comment: When you ran  airflow init db. Have you notice any error?

Comment: No. I did not face any error